# CSS SVG Path - Circular Progress Bar (small ammends)

Tags: html, css, svg

As you will see from the code below I have a lovely circular progress bar however I have a few questions and a little lost on how to achieve this (ideally I don't want to use any JS)

1. I want to make the pink bar that goes around be curved and not
   flat, is this possible? like the edge of it. So instead of it being
   | it would be a little like ) at the start and end.
2. The throbbing circle in the middle, is it possible for it to pause
   for like 1 second once animation is complete before it starts
   again?

```css
/* Load Progress Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes load {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
}
/* Qik Progress Container */

.progress {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Item SVG */

.progress svg {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
.progress svg:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.progress svg:nth-child(2) path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-dasharray: 629;
  stroke: rgba(60, 99, 121, 0.9);
  -webkit-animation: load 8s;
  -moz-animation: load 8s;
  -o-animation: load 8s;
  animation: load 8s;
}
.pulse {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #ff1251;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.45rem;
  left: 1.45rem;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 0.6s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: pulse 0.6s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: pulse 0.6s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 0.6s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes "pulse" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    -o-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes "pulse" {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <svg viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
    <g fill="none" stroke-width="20" transform="translate(100,100)">
      <path d="M-100,0a100,100 0 1,0 200,0a100,100 0 1,0 -200,0" stroke="#FF1252" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </g>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
    <path d="M200,100 C200,44.771525 155.228475,0 100,0 C44.771525,0 0,44.771525 0,100 C0,155.228475 44.771525,200 100,200 C155.228475,200 200,155.228475 200,100 Z" stroke-dashoffset="629"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="pulse"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've re-written the entire code.

For your first question, you could simply use `stroke-linecap="round"`.

For the second one, you will have to add an extra `@keyframes` rule for the delay.

```css
body {
  background: #072237;
}
h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#loader {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
#ring {
  -webkit-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
  animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
}
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #FF1251;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
  animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <svg height="80" width="80" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
    <path id="back" d="M0,100 a100,100 0 1 0 200,0 a100,100 0 1 0 -200,0" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#034870" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path id="ring" d="M100,0 a100,100 0 0 1 0,200 a100,100 0 0 1 0,-200,0" fill="none" stroke="#FF1251" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="629" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="629" />
  </svg>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats lovely mate thanks a load! just a quick one, you know when it grows and shrinks, can it then pause for a second before it grows and shrinks again?

Comment: @JamesBrandon - Check out the update. Is that what you mean? I've updated it again.

Comment: I dont know if i can see the difference, so in theory would be nice for it to: grow / skrink (pause 1 second) grow / shrink (pause 1 second) etc..

Comment: Also noticed its now looping with the progress circle, any way to stop the looping of that? thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @JamesBrandon - Whoops! I get it. I thought you want it to pause at the end(end of the whole load animation). I'll update it again.

Comment: Thanks dude, appriciate it! ive made smaller as well so its 80px x 80px but seems to not look flush at the edges of the pink and background but im playin with that to see if i can sort :)

Comment: @JamesBrandon - Something like this? ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kjxcc6L/)

Comment: Almost, just the other way around so the pause is at the smaller point :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69415/discussion-between-chipchocolate-py-and-james-brandon).

Comment: Is there an unwanted ",0" at the end of the path for "ring"? It doesn't stop the code working, but my browser gives a warning about it.

Answer (score 0):

No. 1. is possible using `stroke-linecap`, but it requires some changes to your code, becasue in your case the red line is actually a background and the gray the stroke - so it would result in a concave circle, so "(", not ")" at the end of the red line. 2. can be done using longer animation set to `alternate` so it "sleeps" between 50% and 100% and back. I've made some changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/3yq3kmo1/

Changes in SVG (the second element):

```
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
    <circle r="100" cx="100" cy="100" stroke-dashoffset="0" />
</svg>
```

CSS (note that the dashoffset has been reversed, so now a red stroke grows and hides the gray, instead of red shrinking and revealing the gray; the `stroke` on path in first SVG element is gray now.)

```
.progress svg:nth-child(2) circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-dasharray: 629;
  stroke: #ff1251;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  animation: load 8s;
}
```

The pause in animation:

```
.pulse {
   animation: pulse 1.6s linear infinite alternate;
 }
 @keyframes pulse {
 0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Ahh thats great, thanks a lot! for some reason the middle pulsing circle is not working though... any ideas?

Comment: Works for me, but I haven't bothered to update all the vendor prefixed code, just the `-webkit-` one.

Comment: Ahh yea i see it now, it gorws stop and shrinks stops, is there a way to grow then shrink then stop and go again? also the animation transition does not seem to be smooth and also noticed you can slightly see the grey behind the pink progress bar... any ideas on those and thanks for all your help! been a masisve help!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: #072237;
}
h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#loader {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
#ring {
  -webkit-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
  animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
}
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #FF1251;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
  animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <svg height="80" width="80" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
    <path id="back" d="M0,100 a100,100 0 1 0 200,0 a100,100 0 1 0 -200,0" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#034870" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path id="ring" d="M100,0 a100,100 0 0 1 0,200 a100,100 0 0 1 0,-200,0" fill="none" stroke="#FF1251" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="629" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="629" />
  </svg>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).